# Find similar rows in specified columns in two excel files with C#

Tags: c#, excel, search

I have two excel files with data like :

File 1 named : FirstFile

```
Code        | Name    | Family
38395334    | John    | Doe
34982323    | Alex    | Carter
94384239    | Sara    | Sancla
```

File 2 named : SecondFile

```
Code        | Name    | Department
38395334    | John    | Doe
113231223   | Mike    | Linoff
            | Alex    | Carter
            | Jimmy  | Carter
```

I want to search across these files like this,
Algorithm first checks the Code column, and similar rows will change color to green.
Then those that don't have Code or they are not found will be searched by Family and Name column and if they are same those rows in both files will change their color to green.

At last all rows that we didn't found will be red.

So rows 1,2 in first file will be green and row 3 will be red.
And rows 1,3 in second file will be green and row 2,4 will be red.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is ok if I write a solution for one file.
In the outer loop you can use an  do-until loop and go through all rows.
Inside this you set  first an boolean for duplicate.
Then u need  three do until loops inside the Outer Loop
where you  check the columns Code, Name and Department. and  if the boolean is true.

So first you check in a loop, if you can find the same code, if this is the case set the row  green  and the boolean true, this will cause that you exit the inner rows and check the next row.

If you cannot find the same code you will exit through the do until  statement, and  go into the Name row where you check if you can find the same name, if this is the case (see above) if not check the department.

When you go through all inner  loops (code, name,  Department) the boolean will be false, if this is the case you set the color to red.

Here you can choose if you change for duplicate in the inner loop or in the outer result.

Just check, that you do not compare row "x" with row "x" else all  rows will be green.